# Facebook Connect open the Facebook App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook

i am trying to implement the facebook connect on my iphone App.

after the first confirm the app stay in the facebook app and dont return to my app.

i call the dialog methood from the view controller with a button but i want to post 
a message about the app when the user logs in how can i do it?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc]initWithAppId:@"" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBEpirationDateKey"])
    {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        [facebook authorize:nil ];
    }
}

-(void)fbDidLogin{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(IBAction)dialog:(id)sender{
    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];
}
```

TNX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable this behavior modify Facebook.m line 275 and set both options to NO.

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
  self.permissions = permissions;

  // with both options NO, authorization always happens in-app
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate you need to implement (make sure you keep a reference to the facebook class instance somewhere where it can be accessed by your app delegate):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: now i am posting trough     [facebook dialog:@"feed" andDelegate:self];

Comment: i want it to happen programatically with a message about the app

Comment: @bentford dude if you read the question properly you will realize that his issue is not with permissions but with the fact that once his app is switched on to Facebook for authentication it never returns to the app whether it's been successful or not. It has everything to do with handleOpenURL and that's why the OP marked my answer as correct. If you're going to downvote at least get it right.

Answer (score -1):

you should [Modify the app property list file](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ios_sso/)

Comment: -1 has nothing to do with property list, and link is bad anyway.